# How to make the url display hostname without www?

Tags: php

How to make the url display hostname without www?

If the URL is

> https://www.google.com/search/

How to make it like this?

> google.com

My code

```
$rgx25 = '/\<a class\=\"live\" rel\=\"nofollow\" href\=\"(|https:\/\/|http:\/\/)(|www\.)(.*?)\" target\=\"\_blank\"\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/iu';
if (preg_match_all($rgx25, $story['text'], $matches))
{
    foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $match)
    {
        $url = $matches[1][$k] . $matches[2][$k] . $matches[3][$k];
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use PHP's `parse_url()` function to get an associative array of the URL parts: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.

Comment: How let url only display main domain by PHP?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855636/how-let-url-only-display-main-domain-by-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://sub.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';
$test = parse_url($url);
$string = explode('.',$test["host"]);
$top_lev_dom = array("com","net","us","gov","io","xyz","org","int","edu");
$output;
$end = false;
$pos = 0;
$pos2;
for($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i++){
    for($x = 0; $x < count(top_lev_dom); $x++){
        if($string[$i]==$top_lev_dom[$x]){
            $pos = $i;
            $pos2 = $i - 1;
            $end = true;
            break;
        }
        if($end == true){break;}
    }
    if($end == true){break;}
}

if($pos==0){
    $output = "error";
}else{
    $output.=$string[$pos2].".".$string[$pos];
}

echo $output;
```

> example.com

Comment: fixing answer give me minute

Comment: if domain is example.com/path?googleguy=googley so to ple.com

Comment: but example.com to com

Comment: because it needs https:// or www. infront of it or do u want that filtered aswell?

Comment: https://www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley and https://example.com/path?googleguy=googley to example.com

Comment: finisheddddddddd

Comment: in the $top_lev_dom = `array("com","net","us","gov","io","xyz","org","int","edu");`                                            just include it in like `array("com","net","us","gov","io","xyz","org","int","edu","ws");`